# How can I gift a Shadowbringers pre-order?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

A friend and I were talking about the new Shadowbringers release date (for FFXIV) and he mentioned that as a gift, he'd buy the add-on for me.

He plays on Steam, and I play on Playstation. How does one go about gifting the other?

I know he'd buy it twice, but does he have to buy the add-on for playstation, and email it to me? Even though we don't play on the same console.

Can anyone else who has been gifted maybe Stormblood help me out?

Comment: If Amazon offers a digital code, could just have them buy the code and give it to you that way. I don't think there's an easy way to gift games/dlc yet, unless they changed the online PS store (I haven't bough directly from there for some time..).

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Thank you for the answer! But, Shadowbringers is a pre-order (well, about to be a pre-order) and I don't think it's available on amazon yet. Maybe he could gift me a PS4 game card, so I can just buy it by myself??

Comment: He could definitely do that. The only thing there is, the gift cards only come in specific amounts (I believe). So he'd have to buy you a $20 card (for example), but the DLC might only be $15 (again, just an example). Even if it happened to be $20, there may be extra taxes and such, so the total might be off ($21.40 or something similar) - if you care that much.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I see! Okay, I think it's (?)9.99 so there'd be a small tax, but you're right about the exact number type thing. It's $10, $20, $30, etc. Either way, thanks a bunch xx

Comment: I had bought the Stormblood expansion for my friend who plays on PS4 from Gamestop, it was a pre-order I believe. I just gave him a code that was on the receipt, and he was able to redeem it on his account. Idk if it would be different this time around, or if it would work differently from a non-Gamestop retailer

Comment: Amazon usually offers preorders, check back after pre-orders begin and see if it shows up on their listings.  You've got several months before the expansion releases so pre-ordering on Feb 7th instead of the 6th won't make much of a difference.  They'll almost certainly have physical disc pre-orders (which are easy to gift), and if they do digital ones you have to apply it to your account somehow because SE doesn't know you bought it from Amazon, so he could give you that license code.

Comment: I think if you buy from either the PS4 store or the Mogstation it will automatically apply to the purchaser's account, so just watch out for those two places.